# Why some public methods of EditText can't be called from Xamarin code?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I make a custom Renderer class for Xamarin.Forms.Entry to customize an Entry then i realize that some public method of EditText control of Android can't be called from my Xamarin code. For example: The method getCompoundDrawablePadding() is a public method of TextView, which is a parent class of EditText.
Is there anyway to call any public methods of EditText from Xamarin code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the public property [CompoundDrawablePadding](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Android.Widget.TextView.CompoundDrawablePadding/).  Most Android get/set methods are exposed in Xamarin as C# properties with getter/setters.